# Keyboard does not appear on fire tv with apache cordova

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, amazon-fire-tv

I've created a small HTML5 [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.incoder.WebViewApp) with apache cordova and jquery mobile with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. On android smartphones and tablets it is running fine.
But on amazon fire tv, the soft keyboard will not appear on input fields.

The html code is like this:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="addPageName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="addPageName" id="addPageName" value="" />
     </div>
</div>
```

I have already tried to add

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

to the config.xml, so that you do not have to klick on the input field, but the keyboard stil does not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that amazon has released a new fire os update, the keyboard is appearing and it is working fine.